# Compare two data sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The issue I'm faced with is I have two sheets of data in Excel. They are a stocksheet list, listing items that have a variance from a stocktake. The items are randomly placed between both documents, so it is almost impossible to do a side-by-side view even if I were to order the columns (which I already have). For example it would be like this:

Sheet 1:

```
A1 (Apple) (1)
A2 (Carrot) (-3)
A3 (Banana) (4)
A4 (Chocolate (-7)
```

Whereas Sheet 2 may be:

```
A1 (Orange) (-2)
A2 (Apple) (3)
A3 (Muffin) (-8)
A4 (Carrot) (3)
```

So as you can see, the same data may appear, and if it does I want to compare those two sets, to know the variance, i.e. Sheet 1 said -3 whereas sheet 2 said +1... I preferably would like to do this in a batch if possible, as there are over 800 cells to go through.

Just so that you can see what I'm dealing with, here's links to pastebins of both sheets;

Sheet 1: http://pastebin.com/6i7QKJ6N
Sheet 2: http://pastebin.com/zjtC2U7q

Is there anything anyone can think of that would be able to assist me, other than me going through this one by one which I am considering doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the unique identifier for the stock items is the column labelled `CYSKU`, right?

If that's so, then there are only 192 common items between the two sheets. I ran a vlookup in both sheets a bit similar to the one pnuts used and used a filter.

There are more variances between CYCOST than with CYRETL as far as I can see (I haven't compared the other columns).

To perform the comparison, you can do the following:

1. Insert a column between columns C and F (just after `CYSKU`) and put a vlookup formula in row 2 of this column and fill it down:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(C2, Sheet2!C:C, 1, 0)
   ```
2. Insert a filter and filter out `#N/A` from this column to get only those that are common between the two sheets.
3. In column M (after CYDVAR), insert another vlookup and fill it down:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(C2, Sheet2!C:F, 4, 0)
   ```

   This will give you the corresponding CYRETL from Sheet2. You can then compare the two CYRETL.

How VLOOKUP works:

1. The first parameter is what VLOOKUP will be looking for.
2. The second parameter is the table range in which to look the first parameter.
3. The third parameter is the *n*th column from which a match will be returned, limited to the table (if the table is in column A:A, only 1 column is available, if the table is A:B, 2 columns are available, etc).
4. The last parameter is for either exact or approximate match. Exact is `0` (or `FALSE`) and approximate is `1` (or `TRUE`).

You can just change the table range and the column number to change the value you're looking for from Sheet2.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me from avoiding the real situation and sticking with your example. Assuming the values are in ColumnB in the corresponding rows, then:

in Sheet1:  `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`
in Sheet2:  `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)`

say in ColumnsC should 'align' the entries (where both exist, otherwise #N/A). `=B1=C1` in D1 copied down should then help to identify the mismatches and say `=B1-C1` in E1 copied down the quantification the discrepancies between the sheets, by 'vegetable'.

There should be no need for a batch mode for this.